# Max date and order by status exist at first occurrence if not found next value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below

```
ID,DATE,Status
359,2021-05-01,M
359,2021-05-01,R
359,2021-04-01,M
759,2021-05-01,R
759,2021-04-01,O
123,2021-05-01,M
123,2021-04-01,O
123,2021-03-31,U
```

and I want the result as below

```
359,2021-05-01,R
759,2021-05-01,R
123,2021-05-01,M
```

Date - Max/Latest date

Status:

- First preference should be R(Exit if R found)
- If R doesn't exist then M
- If M doesn't exist then O
- If O doesn't exist then U etc.,

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far? What's blocking you, the max date or selecting the R/M/O/U letters? For your question to be answered at best, it should not be two questions combined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by case status when 'R' then 1 when 'M' then 2 when 'O' then 3 when 'U' then 4 else 5 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you know all the statuses, a shortcut is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by charindex('RMOU', status)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply :), i will test this and update.

Comment: Hi quick question... how do i join another table for this ? - where table1.id=table2.id and above set

Comment: @Yum.Vee . . . This answers the question that you asked here which is about *one* table.  If you have a different question, ask as a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as suggested for a single table. I created anther question with join example with desired result set. Thank you again for the help